# How to fix crash issue caused by "libGLESv2_adreno.so (A4xTextureObject::IsAstcSrgba()+75)" while drawing frame by grafika on Nexus 6?

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0

I use gles part in [grafika](https://github.com/google/grafika), but it cashes on Nexus 6(Android 5.0). I add the debug information as following:

```
/**
 * Issues the draw call.  Does the full setup on every call.
 *
 * @param mvpMatrix       The 4x4 projection matrix.
 * @param vertexBuffer    Buffer with vertex position data.
 * @param firstVertex     Index of first vertex to use in vertexBuffer.
 * @param vertexCount     Number of vertices in vertexBuffer.
 * @param coordsPerVertex The number of coordinates per vertex (e.g. x,y is 2).
 * @param vertexStride    Width, in bytes, of the position data for each vertex (often
 *                        vertexCount * sizeof(float)).
 * @param texMatrix       A 4x4 transformation matrix for texture coords.  (Primarily intended
 *                        for use with SurfaceTexture.)
 * @param texBuffer       Buffer with vertex texture data.
 * @param texStride       Width, in bytes, of the texture data for each vertex.
 */
public boolean draw(float[] mvpMatrix, FloatBuffer vertexBuffer, int firstVertex,
                 int vertexCount, int coordsPerVertex, int vertexStride,
                 float[] texMatrix, FloatBuffer texBuffer, int textureId, int texStride) {
    if (!GlUtil.checkGlError("draw start")) {
        return false;
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "mvpMatrix.length:" + mvpMatrix.length + ", vertexBuffer:" + vertexBuffer
            + ",firstVertex:" + firstVertex + ",vertexCount:" + vertexCount + ",coordsPerVertex:" + coordsPerVertex
    + "texMatrix:" + texMatrix + ", texMatrix.length:" + texMatrix.length + ",textureId:" + textureId + ",texStride:" + texStride);

    // Select the program.
    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramHandle);

    if (!GlUtil.checkGlError("glUseProgram")) {
        return false;
    }

    // Set the texture.
    GLES20.glActiveTexture(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE0);
    GLES20.glBindTexture(mTextureTarget, textureId);

    // Copy the model / view / projection matrix over.
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muMVPMatrixLoc, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
    if (!GlUtil.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv")) {
        return false;
    }

    // Copy the texture transformation matrix over.
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(muTexMatrixLoc, 1, false, texMatrix, 0);
    if (!GlUtil.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv")) {
        return false;
    }

    // Enable the "aPosition" vertex attribute.
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maPositionLoc);
    if (!GlUtil.checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray")) {
        return false;
    }

    // Connect vertexBuffer to "aPosition".
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maPositionLoc, coordsPerVertex,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, vertexStride, vertexBuffer);
    if (!GlUtil.checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer")) {
        return false;
    }

    // Enable the "aTextureCoord" vertex attribute.
    GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(maTextureCoordLoc);
    if (!GlUtil.checkGlError("glEnableVertexAttribArray")) {
        return false;
    }

    // Connect texBuffer to "aTextureCoord".
    GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(maTextureCoordLoc, 2,
            GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false, texStride, texBuffer);
    if (!GlUtil.checkGlError("glVertexAttribPointer")) {
        return false;
    }

    // Populate the convolution kernel, if present.
    if (muKernelLoc >= 0) {
        GLES20.glUniform1fv(muKernelLoc, KERNEL_SIZE, mKernel, 0);
        GLES20.glUniform2fv(muTexOffsetLoc, KERNEL_SIZE, mTexOffset, 0);
        GLES20.glUniform1f(muColorAdjustLoc, mColorAdjust);
    }

    Log.i(TAG, "draw 000000000 firstVertex:" + firstVertex + ",vertexCount:" + vertexCount);
    // Draw the rect.
    GLES20.glDrawArrays(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, firstVertex, vertexCount);
    if (!GlUtil.checkGlError("glDrawArrays")) {
        return false;
    }
    Log.i(TAG, "draw 1111111111");

    // Done -- disable vertex array, texture, and program.
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(maPositionLoc);
    Log.i(TAG, "draw 2222222");
    GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(maTextureCoordLoc);
    Log.i(TAG, "draw 3333333");
    GLES20.glBindTexture(mTextureTarget, 0);
    GLES20.glUseProgram(0);
    Log.i(TAG, "draw 4444444");
    return true;
}
```

The logs as following:

```
09-22 06:54:48.216 I/GlUtil  ( 3797): draw 000000000 firstVertex:0,vertexCount:4
09-22 06:54:48.216 I/GlUtil  ( 3797): draw 1111111111
09-22 06:54:48.216 I/GlUtil  ( 3797): draw 2222222
09-22 06:54:48.217 I/GlUtil  ( 3797): draw 3333333
09-22 06:54:48.217 I/GlUtil  ( 3797): draw 4444444
09-22 06:54:48.224 W/ActivityManager(  830): getTasks: caller 10093 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output 
09-22 06:54:48.247 I/DEBUG   ( 3746): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
09-22 06:54:48.247 I/DEBUG   ( 3746): Build fingerprint: 'google/shamu/shamu:5.0/LRX21O/1570415:user/release-keys'
09-22 06:54:48.248 I/DEBUG   ( 3746): Revision: '33696'
09-22 06:54:48.248 I/DEBUG   ( 3746): ABI: 'arm'
09-22 06:54:48.248 I/DEBUG   ( 3746): pid: 3797, tid: 4379, name: MovieEncoder  >>> com.camera.demo <<<
09-22 06:54:48.248 I/DEBUG   ( 3746): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x10
09-22 06:54:48.267 W/ActivityManager(  830): getTasks: caller 10093 does not hold GET_TASKS; limiting output 
09-22 06:54:48.294 I/DEBUG   ( 3746):     r0 00000000  r1 00000006  r2 00000000  r3 a3733690
09-22 06:54:48.294 I/DEBUG   ( 3746):     r4 0000000c  r5 afeb6a00  r6 00000001  r7 00000000
09-22 06:54:48.294 I/DEBUG   ( 3746):     r8 af55b440  r9 00000001  sl af768ea4  fp 9b03765c
09-22 06:54:48.294 I/DEBUG   ( 3746):     ip 00000000  sp 9d001798  lr ab502525  pc ab502540  cpsr 800f0030
09-22 06:54:48.295 I/DEBUG   ( 3746): 
09-22 06:54:48.295 I/DEBUG   ( 3746): backtrace:
09-22 06:54:48.295 I/DEBUG   ( 3746):     #00 pc 0012c540  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (A4xTextureObject::IsAstcSrgba()+75)
09-22 06:54:48.295 I/DEBUG   ( 3746):     #01 pc 0012fc0f  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (A4xContext::SetupAstcSrgbaMask()+210)
09-22 06:54:48.295 I/DEBUG   ( 3746):     #02 pc 00137a35  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (A4xContext::ValidateState(EsxDrawDescriptor const*)+1372)
09-22 06:54:48.295 I/DEBUG   ( 3746):     #03 pc 00137ca5  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (A4xContext::HwValidateGfxState(EsxDrawDescriptor const*)+8)
09-22 06:54:48.295 I/DEBUG   ( 3746):     #04 pc 001079ef  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::ValidateGfxState(EsxDrawDescriptor const*)+366)
09-22 06:54:48.295 I/DEBUG   ( 3746):     #05 pc 00107a79  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::DrawArraysInstanced(EsxPrimType, int, unsigned int, unsigned int)+104)
09-22 06:54:48.295 I/DEBUG   ( 3746):     #06 pc 000a9511  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxContext::GlDrawArrays(unsigned int, int, int)+52)
09-22 06:54:48.295 I/DEBUG   ( 3746):     #07 pc 000da2b3  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (EsxGlApiParamValidate::GlDrawArrays(EsxDispatch*, unsigned int, int, int)+58)
09-22 06:54:48.296 I/DEBUG   ( 3746):     #08 pc 000a0209  /system/vendor/lib/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so (glDrawArrays+44)
09-22 06:54:48.296 I/DEBUG   ( 3746):     #09 pc 010340b7  /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@framework@boot.oat
```

Any suggestions to fix it ?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the format of your texture ? Are you using ASTC / ETC compression ? From the stack trace it would seem that the GPU would crash when checking something related to the texture format ... You should also ask on the [Adreno forum](https://developer.qualcomm.com/forums/software/adreno-gpu-sdk)

Comment: @VB_overflow Thanks for your information. I use this to create a texture: `GLES20.glGenTextures(1, textures, 0);`

Comment: I would be more interested to have the glTexImage2D call, which specifies the format of the texture ... especially `internalFormat` and `format`parameter (see [here](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/html/glTexImage2D.xhtml))

Comment: @VB_overflow 
       `GLES20.glTexImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, /*level*/ 0, format,
                width, height, /*border*/ 0, format, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);`

Comment: @VB_overflow The detailed information is here: https://github.com/google/grafika/blob/master/src/com/android/grafika/gles/GlUtil.java

Comment: @VB_overflow Hi, could you please give me more informations. Thanks very much!

Comment: Hi @fadden, Could you please give me some suggestions? Thanks very much!

Comment: @VB_overflow Hi, could you please give me more informations. Thanks very much!

Comment: @Denny it seems that the OpenGLES driver of the device crashed, which normally should not happen (you should get a gl error in normal conditions if there was an issue). The crash occurs while trying to render something with a texture, when trying to validate the texture format. My guess is that the texture would be in a format not supported by the device (ASTC2 maybe ?) so what you can try maybe is using a texture in raw format or changing the shader to not use a texture as a test, to see if crash still happens or not